# How can I change the behavior of hotkeys in xmonad if the program is running?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xmonad

I'm using a few key mappings in my `xmonad.hs` configuration file:

```
...
    , modMask = mod4Mask     -- Rebind Mod to the Windows key
...
 [ ((controlMask, xK_Print), spawn "sleep 0.2; scrot -s")
 , ((0, xK_Print), spawn "scrot")
 , ((controlMask, xK_f), spawn "firefox")
 ]
```

The third mapping runs `firefox` when pressing <kbd>ctrl+f</kbd>. I'd like to do something more complex:

```
if (firefox is running):
  focus and maximize firefox window:
else:
  run firefox
```

And I'd like to change <kbd>ctrl+f</kbd> to <kbd>win+f</kbd>. How can I do that?

Comment: Is crossposting like this (here and on stackoverflow) really an usual business?

Comment: No: it is actively discouraged...

Comment: It's off-topic on SO, so I asked them to get rid of their copy

Comment: @dmitry.malikov This seems to be better place for the question.

Comment: Even better; xralf deleted the SO copy. Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at [XMonad's contrib packages](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/index.html), you'll find [`XMonad.Actions.WindowGo`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-WindowGo.html), which exports the [following function](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-WindowGo.html#v%3arunOrRaiseMaster):

```
runOrRaiseMaster :: String -> Query Bool -> X ()
```

which takes a string argument of the program to **run**, e.g. "firefox"; and a boolean query that is used **to find out if it is already running**, via X11 properties, e.g. `(className =? "Firefox")` (see top of the [`XMonad.Actions.WindowGo` page](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-WindowGo.html) for variants).

So, all you need is to bind `runOrRaiseMaster "firefox" (className =? "Firefox")` to the key you want, as [explained in `XMonad.Doc.Extending`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Doc-Extending.html#Editing_key_bindings), via

```
((modMask, xK_f ), runOrRaiseMaster "firefox" (className =? "Firefox"))
```

as part of the key bindings `Data.Map` of your configuration (details differ with your way of settings this up, i.e, the whole of your `xmonad.hs`, see [Adding Keybindings](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Doc-Extending.html#g:10)).

**Note** that there is no real sense in *maximizing a window* in XMonad.  When you set things up as explained, you'll have <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> act as follows:

- if there's a window with a classname matching "Firefox", **it will be focused** and **set to master**, i.e., depending on your recent [layout](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Doc-Extending.html#g:5), will be *the big window*
- if no window matches, Firefox will be **spawned** and **set to master**.

Maximizing can be emulated by choosing the `Full` layout after calling `runOrRaiseMaster`, [as is described here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/General_xmonad.hs_config_tips#Binding_keys_to_a_specific_layout):

```
("M-<F1>", sendMessage $ JumpToLayout "Full")
```

(note that this example also demonstrates [`XMonad.Util.EZConfig`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xmonad-contrib/0.10/doc/html/XMonad-Util-EZConfig.html) allowing easier keybinding definitions)

**Combining** these two things is possible, too.  Both are of type `X ()`, i.e., they are *in the X Monad*.
Using `>>`, which is of type (check with `:t (>>)` in `ghci`)

```
(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
```

we have `(runOrRaiseMaster "firefox" (className =? "Firefox")) >> (sendMessage $ JumpToLayout "Full")` as a combination of two `X ()` types of type `X ()`, too, and it can thus be bound to a key.

**EDIT Missing `)` in the code line with `>>`**

**Edit2** `modm` -> `modMask`.

**Edit3** [This `xmonad.hs` hopefully works.](http://pastebin.com/APnmXuZj)

([Why not learn you a Haskell for great good?](http://learnyouahaskell.com/))

Comment: Thank you for working answer and other information and Haskell tutorial. I like Haskell syntax and functional paradigm. The only thing that doesn't work is the part `>> (sendMessage $ JumptoLayout "Full")` there is some error with constructor. Maybe it's something easy, that I will solve after learning Haskell.

Comment: I forgot : Yet the `modm` doesn't work, I'm still using `controlMask`.

Comment: @xralf, (1) there was a missing bracket - does it work now?  (2) I'd need your whole `xmonad.hs` to fix this; better just [have a look around here, the config archive](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Config_archive) and see how others do it or use the mentioned `EZConfig`.

Comment: The bracket did not helped. [Here](http://pastebin.com/xqfkh8bk) is the xmonad.hs file I'm using.

Comment: (1) The brackets are still wrong, the action of type `X ()` to bind to the key should be `(runOrRaiseMaster ...) >> (sendMessage ...)`, resulting in `,((...,...), (runOrR...) >> (send...) )`  (a `(` before `run...`)

Comment: (2) Either try `modMask` instead of `controlMask` (as it is set to `mod4Mask` in your config) or use [`XMonad.Util.EZConfig`s `additionalKeysP` with prettier keyspecs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xmonad-contrib/0.10/doc/html/XMonad-Util-EZConfig.html#v%3AmkKeymap) like `M+f` instead of `(modMask, xK_f)`. (Don't forget to import this function instead, then.)

Comment: Could you please edit my paste and click "create new version of this paste" and post a link? I tried a few version of bracketing but none of them works. The `modMask` doesn't work (it was the key I tried before controlMask, that's quite strange), I will try `EZConfig`